Solutions of $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^2$ (German Math Olympiad 2023, 2nd Round)

Find all integer solutions $(a,b,c)$ with pairwise distinct $a,b,c > 0$, such that the equality $$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^2$$ holds.

How would you approach this problem? I found that the triple $(1,2,3)$ and its permutations are solutions, but are these the only ones?

Suppose $a>b>c$ then
$$\begin{align}
a^3 + 1+2^3 \le a^3 +b^3 +c^3 \le (a+(a-1)+(a-2))^2 &\iff a^3-9a^2+18a\le 0\\
&\iff a(a-3)(a-6) \le 0
\end{align}$$
Then $\color{red}{3\le a \le 6}$.
If $a = 3$ then $(a,b,c) = (3,2,1)$ is the solution.
For $4\le a\le 6$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
a^3 +b^3+1\le a^3 +b^3 +c^3 \le (a+b+b-1)^2 &\iff b^3+a^3 +1\le(2b+a-1)^2\\
&\iff b(b-2)^2+a(a^2 -a+2-4b) \le 0\\
&\iff a^2 -a+2 \le 4b\\
&\iff \color{red}{b\ge \frac{a^2-a+2}{4}}
\end{align}$$
Because $\color{red}{b \le a-1}$, then
$$\begin{align}a-1 \ge b \ge  \frac{a^2-a+2}{4}  &\iff \frac{(a-2)(a-3)}{4} \le 0\\
&\iff2 \le a\le 3 \quad \text{contradiction}\end{align} $$
We conclude that $(a,b,c) = (3,2,1)$ and all permutations are the solutions of the  integer equation.

Just a little follow-up question: Why do $b$ and $c$ stay fixed as $1$ and $2$ in the first inequality? I feel like I am currently missing something.

@Sheep It's because $b>c \ge 1$, then $c \ge 1$ and $b \ge c+1 \ge 2$.

Hint
Assume $a>b>c>0$. Then $a^3<a^3+b^3+c^3<3a^3$ and $a^2<(a+b+c)^2<(3a)^2$. From this, find an upper bound on $a$. You can also get tighter bounds than this by using that the three numbers are distinct. If you do it well, you can reduce to only $4$ possible values of $a$.
